# Which is the best practice for adding a background image?

Tags: android, android-layout

**Which will be the best way to set picture background to a LinearLayout: Setting Background to LinearLayout or Enclosing the LinearLayout in A FramLayout and adding ImageView as first Child?**

*In Detail:*

My goal is to attain an UI like the below attached image.

[image]

I attained this UI by following two ways.
Can someone please explain Which among these would be the best way (in terms of performance and memory)?

**1st Method : Setting background to LinearLayout**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_age"
android:layout_width="95dp"
android:layout_height="95dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/profile_detail_bg">

<ImageView android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/person_age"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="25"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**2nd Method : Using FrameLayout and ImageView**

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_detail_bg"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/person_age"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="25"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Not only the first method looks better to me, but by using a compound drawable, you can get rid of the ImageView and set the image directly into the TextView. So, saving a View (and memory).

Answer (score 1):

The first is probably more standard, but it has limitations (you can't specify scaling, for example).  You should try it, and then move to the second if you can't get the effect you want.  In terms of perf and memory, the first will be slightly better due to having fewer views that need to be laid out, measured, etc.  But I wouldn't expect to see any noticable difference

Comment: I tried them both. I was able to achieve what i need by method 1. I guess I will go with it for now, Until I get any more opinions on it. Thanks for the immediate response @gabe-sechan.